# If condition issue in shell

Tags: unix, conditional-statements

I'm trying to detect whether a string holds a dash but nothing seems to work for me (I'm new to shell).

```
if [ "$m" -eq "-" ]
then
echo "has dash"
else
echo "has no dash"
fi
```

Comment: Contains a dash, or is exactly one dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [ "x$m" = "x-" ]; then
    echo "is a dash"
else
    echo "is not a dash"
fi
```

Uses string comparison, quotes everything, and avoids possible `[` command line switch confusion (on some not-quite-Posix shells) if `$m` starts with a `-`.

Answer (score 4):

`-eq` is used for testing equality of integers. To test for string equality, use `=` instead:

```
if [ "$m" = - ]
```

See the man page for `test` for further details.

Comment: Important note: if `$m` is the empty string, this will evaluate to a syntax error.  To prevent that, a common idiom is to test `if [ "x$m" = x- ]`.

Comment: Actually, with the `"$m"` quotes around `$m`, there will be an empty string on `[`'s `args` list, and therefore no syntax error. The reason for quoting stuff beginning with `x` is to prevent the problems when `$m` starts with a `-` and `[` interprets it as a command line switch.

Comment: @Adam I don't get a syntax error in bash (version 3.1). The empty double quotes are treated as the first argument.

Comment: @ndim I also don't see any problems when `$m` starts with a `-`.

Comment: I personally have not observed problems either, but then I have not tested a similar number of Unix shells the Autoconf people need their shell code run on. In http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/autoconf/Limitations-of-Builtins.html, they write that Posix says `[ "..." = "..." ]` should work for every possible string, but in reality, you do run into issues on some systems if the string starts with `-`.

Answer (score 1):

The '-eq' operator performs an arithmetic comparison.  You need to use the '=' operator instead.  ie:

if test "$m" = '-'; then
    echo "is a dash";
else
    echo "has no dash";
fi